# UPDATE data not working with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a simple MySQL UPDATE statement, selecting `id_pt` from table `tbl_pt` and update not working appears a error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id_pt = '1'' at line 6`

a simple code for update `aksi_identitas.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['namauser']) AND empty($_SESSION['passuser'])){
  echo "<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <center>Untuk mengakses modul, Anda harus login <br>";
  echo "<a href=../../index.php><b>LOGIN</b></a></center>";
}
else{
include "../../../config/koneksi.php";

$module=$_GET[module];
$act=$_GET[act];

// Update identitas
if ($module=='identitas' AND $act=='update'){

    $c = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_pt SET nama_pt   = '$_POST[nama_pt]',
                                             alamat_pt   = '$_POST[alamat_pt]',
                                             phone_pt     = '$_POST[phone_pt]',
                                               email_pt   = '$_POST[email_pt]',
                                               fax_pt     = '$_POST[fax_pt]',
                                WHERE id_pt   = '$_POST[id]'");
    if ($c) {
      header('location:../../media.php?module='.$module);
    }else{
      echo "Gagal ".mysql_error();
    }
  }
}
?>
```

And `identitas.php`

```
<?php
  $aksi="modul/mod_identitas/aksi_identitas.php";
  switch($_GET[act]){
  // Tampil identitas
  default:
    $sql  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_pt LIMIT 1");
    $r    = mysql_fetch_array($sql);


   echo "
   <div id='main-content'>
   <div class='container_12'>
   <div class='grid_12'>
   </div>

   <div class='grid_12'>
   <div class='block-border'>
   <div class='block-header'>
   <h1>IDENTITAS PERUSAHAAN</h1>
   <span></span> 
   </div>
   <div class='block-content'>

    <form method=POST enctype='multipart/form-data' action=$aksi?module=identitas&act=update>
    <input type=hidden name=id value=$r[id_pt]>

    <p class=inline-small-label> 
    <label for=field4>Nama Perusahaan</label>
    <input type=text name='nama_pt' size=50 value='$r[nama_pt]'>
    </p>    

    <p class=inline-small-label> 
    <label for=field4>Alamat Perusahaan</label>
    <input type=text name='alamat_pt' size=50 value='$r[alamat_pt]'>
    </p> 

    <p class=inline-small-label> 
    <label for=field4>Telepon Perusahaan</label>
    <input type=text name='phone_pt' size=50 value='$r[phone_pt]'>
    </p>

    <p class=inline-small-label> 
    <label for=field4>Email Perusahaan</label>
    <input type=text name='email_pt' size=50 value='$r[email_pt]'>
    </p>

    <p class=inline-small-label> 
    <label for=field4>Fax Perusahaan</label>
    <input type=text name='fax_pt' size=50 value='$r[fax_pt]'>
    </p>";

    echo "<div class=block-actions> 
      <ul class=actions-right> 
      <li>
      <a class='button red' id=reset-validate-form href='?module=identitas'>Batal</a>
      </li> </ul>
      <ul class=actions-left> 
      <li>
      <input type='submit' name='upload' class='button' value='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Simpan &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'>
      </form>";

    break;  
   }
  ?>


   </div> 
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class='clear height-fix'></div> 
   </div></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Remove `,` `comma` after `'$_POST[fax_pt]',`

Comment: Then you can accept my answer as I have posted it..

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra comma before `WHERE`